# Is there still a limit of 100m ethernet cable between two FDX switches?

Tags: ethernet

If the connection is just between two switches, there can be no collisions.
So shouldn't the switches be able to cope with much longer delays than the standard 100m?

Comment: https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/q/18541/645

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 100 m limit is not only for ensuring collision detection (which isn't used in FDX) but the longer the distance the more signal attenuation and crosstalk increase. 100 m is the length where everything is guaranteed to still be in spec.

Considering the notable headroom for the 100BASE-TX signal over Cat-5e cable (or even better), you may well get away with a longer cable - but there's no guarantee and you'll be on your own.

Comment: So a "better" cable would allow for longer length. Make sense. Because fibre allows for several kilometers.

Comment: Not necessarily though it might. ;-) Watch for the plenum vs patch cable difference - patch has a much higher attenuation and will not support more than ca. 30 m (officially only 10 m!). Fiber has different limitations such as mode dispersion in MMF - SMF has few limitations besides (very low) attenuation.